# X11 module ABI version does not match server's version

Tags: debian, xorg

When using startx on my 32 bit linux system running debian  Jessie, I get the following error:

```
(EE) module ABI major version (12) doesn't match server's version (15)
(EE) no screens found
```

`tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log` (Above the information already stated)

```
Module fbturbo: vendor="X.org foundation"
Compiled for 1.12.4 module version 0.3.1
ABI class: X.org video driver, version 12.1
Failed to load module "fbturbo" (module requirement mismatch"
```

I did google and found many results, but none of them reference versions 12 and 15 and none relate to Debian. How can I get X11 to work again?

Here's the entire xorg.0.log:

```
[  1035.404] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.0.901 (1.15.1 RC 1)
Release Date: 2014-03-21
[  1035.409] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1035.411] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13-1-armmp armv7l Raspbian
[  1035.412] Current Operating System: Linux raspi 3.10.37+ #669 PREEMPT Tue Apr 15 14:44:32 BST 2014 armv6l
[  1035.413] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1280 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=720 bcm2708.boardrev=0xf bcm2708.serial=0xbc6c8748 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:6C:87:48 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait quiet loglevel=0
[  1035.419] Build Date: 06 April 2014  07:54:41AM
[  1035.423] xorg-server 2:1.15.0.901-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[  1035.430] Current version of pixman: 0.32.4
[  1035.431]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1035.432] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1035.444] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Apr 23 15:54:06 2014
[  1035.451] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1035.459] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1035.460] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1035.460] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1035.460] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1035.467] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  1035.467] (**) |   |-->Device "Allwinner A10/A13 FBDEV"
[  1035.468] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1035.468] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1035.469] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1035.469] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1035.471] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[  1035.471]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1035.472] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1035.472]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1035.472] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1035.473]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1035.473] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1035.473]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1035.475] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1035.475]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1035.476] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1035.476]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1035.476] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  1035.476] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1035.477] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1035.477] (II) Loader magic: 0xb6f9fef8
[  1035.478] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1035.479]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1035.479]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[  1035.479]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[  1035.480]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[  1035.483] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  1035.484] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  1035.485] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  1035.486] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  1035.487] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  1035.488] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  1035.489] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  1035.490] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  1035.491] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  1035.501] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  1035.516] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  1035.527] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  1035.536] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  1035.547] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  1035.557] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  1035.566] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  1035.576] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1035.585] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1035.593] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  1035.602] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  1035.613] Initializing built-in extension Present
[  1035.621] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[  1035.629] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  1035.638] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[  1035.646] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1035.655] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[  1035.663] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1035.671] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[  1035.678] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[  1035.686] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[  1035.687] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1035.692] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1035.700] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1035.701]    compiled for 1.15.0.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  1035.702]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[  1035.703] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1035.713] Loading extension GLX
[  1035.713] (II) LoadModule: "fbturbo"
[  1035.718] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbturbo_drv.so
[  1035.721] (II) Module fbturbo: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1035.722]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 0.3.1
[  1035.723]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1035.723]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[  1035.731] (EE) module ABI major version (12) doesn't match the server's version (15)
[  1035.731] (II) UnloadModule: "fbturbo"
[  1035.732] (II) Unloading fbturbo
[  1035.733] (EE) Failed to load module "fbturbo" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[  1035.733] (EE) No drivers available.
[  1035.734] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1035.748] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  1035.756] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1035.781] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1035.795] (EE) 
[  1035.809] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Have you made sure you've updated all the packages for xorg ?

Comment: I do not know which ones I need to update. Which package contains the module ABI? aptitude update and upgrade show that nothing needs upgrading and nothing is held back.

Comment: have you run `aptitude full-upgrade` ?

Comment: Yes I always do

Comment: Post the compleete file `Xorg.0.log`. You didn't include the lines that we need to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I just had precisely this problem.  Basically this means that the video driver, in my case provided by parallels tools, needs to be updated.  Here are all the commands I ran, including reconfiguring gnome, which you may not want or need:

```
    # All as root:

    /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop
    Xorg -configure
    /etc/init.d/gdm3 start

    # Looked in the log file:
    vi /var/log/Xorg.0.log # look for breakage!

    ...  prlvideo ... <-- The parallels video driver.
    (EE) module ABI major version (12) doesn't match server's version (15)

    # So I updated parallels tools:

    mount /dev/cdrom
    mount -o remount,ro,exec /dev/cdrom
    cd /media/cdrom0
    ./install

    # And reconfigured:
    shutdown -r now

    /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop
    Xorg -configure
    /etc/init.d/gdm3 start


    vi /var/log/gdm3/\:0-greeter.log

    # This contained errors about no 3d acceleration so:
    shutdown -h now

    # Added 3d acceleration in the parallels GUI and restarted.

    And it worked :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not always that simple, it happened to me after an unsuccessful build and install of current bleeding edge LLVM because a current bleeding edge Firefox wanted it.  Seemed to build OK, then the make install couldn't find the fresh Clang so the whole thing bombed and left behind a mess.  Just remember that dpkg -i always works (supposedly) so you can force it to install over an incorrect version.

The versions in my case were:

```
[    46.663] (EE) fbturbo: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)
[    46.663] (EE) Failed to load module "fbturbo" (module requirement mismatch,0)
```

Figure out what you need then install it with dpkg -i <file>.  The files you need are probably already sitting in /var/cache/apt/archives.  You're just reinstalling them.